# Failed full-upgrade. Unmet dependencies

Tags: debian, dist-upgrade

Running mxlinux debian 11. Bunch of unmet dependencies and broken gui. How do I proceed?[image]

Comment: What led up to this?

Comment: Apt dist-upgrade